# Kernel Panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000009 issue can be solved in grub mode or not?

Tags: xubuntu, grubrescue

I updated my Ubuntu to 16.04 from 14.04. Now my PC cannot load it. It produces the following error in every restart

```
Kernel Panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000009
```

Only **grub** command prompt is showing.

Is there any way to recover kernel in **grub** mode?