# Upgrading Xubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.1 hangs at kernel panic

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, xubuntu, systemd

I was running Xubuntu 14.04 LTS, and received 16.04.1 upgrade notify recently, so I did an upgrade.

During the upgrade process some error prompted that "init" does not found or something, but I didn't pay much attention (plus it only gives me a "close" button).

The first time upgrade process tried to reboot, it stops at a blank screen with a non-blinking cursor on upper left. After waiting for quite some time, I did a hard reboot, and then my system hangs at here:

[image]

> Target filesystem doesn't have requested `/sbin/init`
>
> Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill `init`! exitcode=`0x00007f00`

In GRUB's advance menu I can choose these entries:

- *default*, which actually is `systemd`;
- `systemd`;
- `upstart`, which boots into Xubuntu's GUI loading screen, but just that. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and I can see that it stops at

  > Starting cups-browsed - Bonjour remote printer browsing daemon [ OK ]

  <kbd>NumLock</kbd> works, cursor blinking, but nothing else;
- recovery_mode, which boots exactly like `systemd`

Choosing older kernels in GRUB's advance option doesn't make any better: for `systemd` or `recovery-mode` they didn't make any difference; for `upstart` they stops at a black-and-white screen loading 15.10 (which I never installed).

I've read [question #651974](https://askubuntu.com/q/651974/497339), [question #92946](https://askubuntu.com/q/92946/497339), but it doesn't seem to help.

Someone already posted a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/808140/497339) with no answer (currently).

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/592285/308164)?

Comment: @luchonacho Thanks for the comment, but I don't think this answer has anything to do with my problem...I was not using Live USB to install Xubuntu, but upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. No external drive was involved.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made my computer back to life again, but I don't really understand "how", so this is more of a follow up, but I think I'll post it anyway in case someone else encounter similar situation and want a hint.

#### Short story:

I used a Live USB to boot, followed [this instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure) to get into command line, `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get autoremove`, reboot into upstart mode, (sort of) finished the upgrade process.

#### Long story:

When I did the distribution upgrade I found my Internet connection was quite slow, so I mindlessly switched server to cn99 (China), which I think is where the damage came from.

The upgrade is fast, but when it went into first reboot (or I think it was the first reboot), the error in question appears.

Luckily I have another computer around, so I made a Live USB and used it to boot. It doesn't seem to work at first, showing errors like:

> Undef symbol FAIL: __syslinux_shuffler_size
> Failed to load libcom32.c32
> Failed to load COM32 file gfxboot.c32
> boot:

Following [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/tuxboot/+bug/1190256/comments/14), I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>, enter "live" and successfully booted into Xubuntu Live.

Then I followed [this instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure):

> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>
>
> `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
>
> `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
>
> `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
>
> `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
>
> `sudo chroot /mnt`
>
> `apt update`

This was when I was told that my repository was corrupted and need to run `dpkg --configure -a` to correct it.
I also run `apt-get autoremove` since some other Google results suggested to do so.

Then I reboot and tried default (`systemd`) first, still failed, but `upstart` work.
I then check for software update, nothing new, and for some reason (thank god) I switch server back to main, and loads of update appears, and even a "Partial upgrade" window appeared.

I did the Partial upgrade, and at the end of installing it still shows error and just stopped, but the system was responsive, so I reboot (skipping the "Cleaning up" part) using `systemd` and this time it worked.

There's still some minor flaws in my system, but at least it work again.